# Is there a way to sort rows by date with a vba command button

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data entry form for inputting lost and found items into a worksheet, I'm able to search the items but I have a list box for recent entries but obviously the first row is the first item on the list box, is there someway that I can sort rows from the page to the most recent entry by clicking the submit button?

```
Private Sub Submit_Button_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Found_Property")
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
'validation-----------------------------------------------------
If Me.Date_Item_Found_Textbox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter the date the item was found.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Property_Owner_Textbox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter the name of the owner of the property, if not available 
enter N/A.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Location_Found_Combobox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a location the item was found.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Property_Description_Textbox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter a breif description of the item.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Reporting_Officer_Combobox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select your name or the reporting officer's name.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Contact_Number_Textbox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter a valid contact number for the reporting party.", 
vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.Location_Stored_Combobox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select the location of which the item is stored.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------
sh.Range("A" & last_row + 1).Value = "=Row()-2"
sh.Range("B" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Date_Item_Found_Textbox.Value
sh.Range("D" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Property_Owner_Textbox.Value
sh.Range("E" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Contact_Number_Textbox.Value
sh.Range("F" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Location_Found_Combobox.Value
sh.Range("G" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Property_Description_Textbox.Value
sh.Range("H" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Reporting_Officer_Combobox.Value
sh.Range("I" & last_row + 1).Value = Me.Location_Stored_Combobox.Value
sh.Range("J" & last_row + 1).Value = Now
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Me.ID_Textbox = ""
Me.Date_Item_Found_Textbox = ""
Me.Property_Owner_Textbox = ""
Me.Contact_Number_Textbox = ""
Me.Location_Found_Combobox = ""
Me.Property_Description_Textbox = ""
Me.Reporting_Officer_Combobox = ""
Me.Location_Stored_Combobox = ""
'-----
MsgBox "The item has been successfully entered as FOUND PROPERTY"
Call refresh_data
Me.Date_Item_Found_Textbox.SetFocus

Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range

Set myrange = Worksheets("Found_Property").Range("A3:J100")

For Each mycell In myrange

mycell.Value = UCase(mycell.Value)

Next mycell

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but share some code or post what you've tried.

Comment: Im kinda new to coding so Im not even sure how to go about this, I can share the code from the submit button I have if that would help.